# Remove D: or Add C: Drive shortcuts from File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Is it possible to either remove D: from this list or add C:?

[image: File explorer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to either remove D: from this list or add C:?

Well, here is how you can remove `D:`

I actually find this annoying, and so I've hidden the extra drives so they don't show up at all. This prevents flash drives from showing up twice, but it should hide all extra drives from showing up except nested under `This PC`.

I don't remember where I got this from, but you can use a Registry Script to quickly edit the registry to hide those extra drives:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\DelegateFolders\{F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83}]

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\DelegateFolders\{F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83}]
```

Save the above as `RemoveDrives.reg` and right-click and click **Merge**. I don't believe it needs to be run as administrator, but if it doesn't work the first time, try that.

Once you restart File Explorer, the extra drives should no longer be visible.

This reverts File Explorer to the Windows 7 behavior where drives only showed up nested under `Computer` and not anywhere else, in my opinion the more sensible behavior.

Here is a screenshot from my PC when I plug in a USB flash drive. Notice it doesn't show up by itself in the Navigation pane - only once under `This PC`:

[image]

Comment: Found this to article saying the same thing too. https://www.clonefileschecker.com/blog/fix-duplicate-drives-in-windows-10-file-explorer-2/

Comment: @rwilliams Yup, the technique is probably available on numerous webpages. Windows 10 has so many issues that you'll find a huge number of web pages to fix various problems with it, this is just one weirdness that doesn't make a lot of sense but is easily fixable.

Comment: One thing to note is that every time windows does a big os update this gets reset and you have to run the script again. I'm doing the windows insider builds so this happens frequently.

Comment: @rwilliams Interesting, I've not noticed that though I'm not on any the insider track. You could use Group Policy to apply these at startup/logon so you don't have to manually do it again

Answer (score 0):

The shortcuts reflect what drives are connected.

You can right click on Computer, select Manage, then Disk Management and see what letters have been applied to what internal drives.

Then Explorer will use these letters and more letters for any USB drives or Network Drives attached.

So let Explorer use what it needs and there is normally no need to change the letters.

When you disconnect USB drives or Network Drives, those letters will go away from that Explorer session

Look at the screen shot below to help

[image]

Comment: So why doesn't my C: drive show up on that list?

Comment: Open cmd.exe and run DIR   .   Does C: show up?  Also make sure you are looking at the main Explorer window and not Quick Access.   Quick Access might not have C: in its QA cache

Comment: https://imgur.com/HN64aWH Maybe this will clarify

Comment: Your C:  is OS (C:)  .  See my screen shot above.  It is there in your main Explorer Window

Comment: Yes I get that. But i don't understand why my D: drive has a link outside of "this PC" So i'd like to remove that somehow or add C: outside "This pc" as well

Comment: Your D: Drive shows up under PC which is correct. The other representation may be QA cache.  I am not sure of your setup. Certainly what show up under PC (This PC in my screen shot) is correct. Try clearing QA entries. Right Click on QA, options, Clear, OK and then restart Explorer

Comment: @John I don't think it's caching, it's just Windows 10 weirdness where Windows will duplicate all external/removable drives twice for you. There's a registry fix which removes this behavior and makes File Explorer behave like Windows 7 (i.e. every drive shows up only once)

Comment: I do not say any behaviour like you are showing so long a QA is cleared or limited and never any need here to use the registry. All works fine as standard windows