# images from imgur not showing in my posts on SuperUser

Tags: google-chrome

Using Chrome Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit) and it says it's up to date.

I cannot see some images in answers that I posted on this site. In my post I see the broken image icon. When I follow the image link, I'm getting the error

> This site can’t be reached i.stack.imgur.com unexpectedly closed the
>   connection. Try:
>
> Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall Running
>   Windows Network Diagnostics ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Funnily enough, when I open the same post in another Chrome session, the images show fine. Also, for example I can see this image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Wie.png

but not this one.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrWSR.png

I have already cleared cookies. If DNS were the problem, then I shouldn't be seeing the image in the other Chrome session either, right?

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not your issue, but whenever this has happened to me before, it was because I was on a network where IT blocked imgur and so the SO images never loaded

Comment: Can you see the Explorer image in this post?  https://superuser.com/questions/1502205/remove-d-or-add-c-drive-shortcuts-from-file-explorer .  The imgur link is  https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKRxJ.png and it shows in Chrome.  Both your links show in my Chrome (newest version)

Answer (score 1):

Solution: disable VPN.

I was using VPN to work remotely on a client's system. Apparently that means that all my traffic goes through their network and restictions like website bans (imgur) are applied. The images I COULD see were probably from my cache.